# Do I need to read all the supplementary material for The Expanse, and in what order?

Tags: reading-order, the-expanse, james-s-a-corey

I want to read The Expanse, but I'm kind of confused about which to read first and what I actually need to read. So far as I can tell The Expanse is a series of novels that fall in roughly chronological order, but there's also a number of novellas and short stories which jump around the chronology.

I figure the shorter stuff is going to be harder to find (published in magazines, etc). Does it matter what order I read the non-novel material in? Can/should I skip the non-novel material entirely?

Comment: Kind of related - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150017/can-i-read-abaddons-gate-without-having-read-the-previous-books-in-the-expans

Answer (score 6):

Corey has suggested they are best read in publication order, (main novels in bold):

> **Leviathan Wakes (2011)**
>   The Butcher of Anderson Station (2011)
>   **Caliban's War (2012)**
>   Gods of Risk (2012)
>   Drive (2012)
>   **Abaddon's Gate (2013)**
>   The Churn (2014)
>   **Cibola Burn (2014)**
>   **Nemesis Games (2015)**
>   The Vital Abyss (2015)
>   **Babylon's Ashes (2016)**
>   Untitled Expanse Novella (TBP)
>   **Persepolis Rising (TBP)**

However another good reading order, and IMO the better one, would be as follows (again main novels in bold, and note that I've jumbled short stories, novellas etc. under one title 'short story'):

> Drive - Short story published November 27, 2012.
>   The Churn - Short story published April 29, 2014
>   The Butcher of Anderson Station - Short story published October 17, 2011
>   **Leviathan Wakes** - Novel published June 15, 2011
>   **Caliban’s War** - Novel published June 26, 2012
>   Gods of Risk - Short story published September 15, 2012
>   **Abaddon’s Gate** - Novel published June 4, 2013
>   The Vital Abyss - Short story published October 15, 2015
>   **Cibola Burn** - Novel published June 17, 2014
>   **Nemesis Games** - Novel published June 2, 2015
>   **Babylon’s Ashes** - Novel published December 6, 2016
>   Untitled Expanse Novella - Short story to be published
>   **Persepolis Rising** - Novel to be published 2017

Also note there are a few more being written, and several planned as well. And if you want to be pedantic, you could technically say that [The Martian should be read first](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153017/are-the-expanse-and-the-martian-set-in-the-same-universe).

I personally think the second order is better as it makes a better read. It makes more sense and nothing happens which you need knowledge from another book that hasn't been read yet to understand. Although obviously I have no idea where the unpublished ones should go, so I've placed them chronologically.

Comment: Can you please expand on why your second option is preferable?

Comment: Are you saying that reading in publication order would cause unintended confusion?

Comment: You should note that your second option is the chronological in-universe order and the first one is publication order.

Comment: I don’t see those two listings in your previous comments. Where can they be found and when were they published?

Comment: About the second order: reading The Churn before any of the books will take away the twist/suspense of The Churn.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only "mandatory" novella is 'The Churn'. It contains information that is relevant, especially in 'Nemesis Games'. Read the books in order, and make sure to read 'The Churn' somewhere before 'Nemesis Games'.

'The Vital Abyss' is semi-important to the overall plot, so reading it before 'Babylon' or 'Percepolis' will certainly add to the experience.

The other novellas are more world building, which contributes to the depth of The Expanse universe, but I don't consider them vital to the plot in the books. (Also, I didn't like the earliest novellas too much. They were OK, but nowhere near as good as the books.)

UPDATE
I higly recommend reading Strange Dogs before Tiamat.